# How can you set the BindingContext on a xamarin contentPage without triggering binding

Tags: xamarin.forms, model-binding

How can you set the BindingContext on a xamarin ContentPage with out triggering binding. Does anyone know if this is possible. I think what i am after is something like the WindowsForms SuspendBinding method

Comment: I don't think it is possible... And I wonder why should you need such a thing in this environment?

Comment: I don't want the user to see bound interface controls changes as the view model initializes.

Comment: I got it. I suggest you to start to think about another approach, once it's highly unprobable you disable the internals binding triggers. What do you say about the facebook strategy: an animated template is shown until the data is loaded (https://i.stack.imgur.com/h71ha.jpg)

Comment: I would not get sign off on that :-(

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand. My English is too poor =). But if you mean it's too hard, I don't think so. Make a try and we will help if you get stuck.

Comment: What i mean is that the people paying me to write the app don't want a spinner as the pages loads..

Comment: Hmmn. All right then. Good luck then